# Which Realtek High Definition Audio Driver to download for Windows 10?

Tags: realtek-hd-audio

I have a Lenovo laptop (32 bit Windows 10) and for some reason the Realtek HD Audio Manager is missing. I have been trying to find the right Realtek High Definition Audio Driver to download, but so far I have only been able to find this [download link](https://realtek-download.com/download-hd/). The link is confusing because for version 2.82 it gives the following choices that I think that they all apply to my case -

- Realtek HD Audio Driver (Vista/7/8/8.1/10) 32-bit (Executable file) (168 MB)
- Vista, Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10 Driver (32/64bits) Driver only (Executable file) (412  MB)
- Vista, Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10 Driver (32/64bits) Driver only (ZIP file) (417 MB)
- Realtek High Definition Audio Drivers (2k/2k3/XP) (30.5 MB)

  I don't know which one is the right one to download. Please help! And thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to update the drivers through windows update? (Go into "device manager", right click your audio device, click "Update drivers" and then "Search online for drivers")

Comment: Also use Lenovo System Update to update your drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to explain the differences between each as they appear and post a conclusion on which one you should choose.

**Realtek HD Audio Driver** is a driver with a companion program that comes with it for configuring sound options. It comes as an executable so it is an installer for ease of use.

**Driver only (Executable file)** is the audio drivers to allow your sound to work, but does not come with the optional program that allows you to configure volume and effects, you would have to use the default Windows 10 volume slider. this comes also in an executable, which means it is a one-click install as well.

**Driver only (ZIP File)** is the above, except it comes in a ZIP file. Contents of this zip file may just be a compressed executable or it may require an alternative way to install the driver. I wouldn't recommend this unless you already know why you would need this as it for most users just adds unnecessary headache.

**Realtek High Definition Audio Drivers** appears to be a legacy driver for Windows 2000, Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP. You don't need this.

Conclusion:

If you are looking to just fix sound issues, pick the second option. If you are looking for additional functionality like sound effects, get the first option. The third and fourth option are simply there for people who are looking for them essentially.